# How can I round the coefficient of a term containing symbolic variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rounding, digits

Friends,I need to round off a term containing symbolic variables to zero when its coefficient is numerically very small value.

For eg: in the following expression:

**4.5*h + 6.12e-17*cos(q)**

I need to round off the second term to zero as its coefficient is very small.

(q and h are symbolic varialbes)

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

(for those who want to have more details on how I arrived at that expression:

This was my preliminary result:

**(4967757600021511*cos(q))/81129638414606681695789005144064**

I used VPA to convert this to decimal form and the result obtained was

**0.00000000000000006123233995736766035868820147292*cos(q)**

Then, I set the no:of significant digits to 3 and the result was:

**6.12e-17*cos(q)**